# Integration of Apache Airflow with Google cloud pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, airflow

I am quite new to airflow and trying to use the integration of apache airflow with google pubsub, which I guess is added to it under "Airflow-300" JIRA. Please correct me if I am reading incorrectly here.

Also, can you please advise if this has been released or when will it be released? We are looking at adding notifications on Google Cloud Storage, upon any file events, we want to trigger some workflow in Airflow.

I can't seem to find any documentation around how to use it.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Integration in Airflow has already been introduced.

## Publish message

```py
from base64 import b64encode as b64e

m1 = {'data': b64e('Hello, World!'),
       'attributes': {'type': 'greeting'}
      }
m2 = {'data': b64e('Knock, knock')}
m3 = {'attributes': {'foo': ''}}

t1 = PubSubPublishOperator(
    topic='my_topic',
    messages=[m1, m2, m3],
    create_topic=True,
    dag=dag)
```

## Receive message

```py
PubSubPullSensor(
    task_id='pub_sub_wait', 
    project='my_project',
    subscription='my-subscription',
    ack_messages=True)
```

Reference:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/d231dce37d753ed196a26d9b244ddf376385de38
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/6645218092096e4b10fc737a62bacc2670e1d6dc

Comment: It seems like the above code is in conflict with the example code found here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_pubsub_flow.py. The above produces the error: Broken DAG: [/Users/ethanlyon/airflow/dags/pubsub.py] a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @user1849502's answer, you can also use PubSubHook:

```
PubSubHook().publish(project, topic, message)

PubSubHook().pull(project, subscription, max_messages, return_immediately)
```

Reference https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_pubsub_hook.html